# Ibatis SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ibatis

I have the below query :

```
   Select top 20 * from tab 
--(first query)
   union all
   Select '0' as id,'PR' as BU,tab.name,tab.desc from tablename tab
  inner join tablename1 tab1 ON tab1.name=tab.name and tab1.desc=tab.desc               
--(second query)
  union all
  Select '0' as id,'BR' as BU,tab.name,tab.desc from tablename tab
  inner join tablename1 tab1 ON tab1.name=tab.name and tab1.desc=tab.desc
--(third query)
```

Here i am trying to put the filter in the above query if i pass 'PR' as BU it should give me results of query 1 and query 2 but right now it is giving me results of all the three queries.
I need the results on basis of parameter of BU

Answer (score 0):

There are no parameters in your SQL but this is something that ibatis can help you with.  By using [dynamic SQL](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html) you can have ibatis generate multiple prepared statements and using the correct one at runtime based on input.